# How to tell if a specific li element has been scrolled past the top of a list

Tags: javascript

I have been playing around with this code on my own for a few days now and after using MDN and W3 references made a bit of progress but still notworking out for me.

I have a list of colors and the list is 60vh. Each list item is flippable. when a button is pressed on the list item the class .flipped is added to that list item.

What I want to do inside of a scroll event attached to the color list is detect when the list item containing the .flipped class has been scrolled out of view as you scroll down the list but cant seem to understand how.

So far I have the scroll event attached to the color list and inside I am at the point where I have looped through all of the items to grab the list item with the .flipped class but beyond that am lost.

Any help would be appreciated. Im trying to make it so that if the user flips the list item and scrolls it out of view that a link will appear above the list. When this link is pressed I want it to scroll the flipped item back into view like a bookmark. That part I can cover but as I said Its the detection im having trouble with. Thank everyone.

```
var color_list = document.getElementById('color-list');
var list_items = color_list.getElementsByClassName('color-list-item');
var flipped_item = undefined;

color_list.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < list_items.length; i++) {

        if(list_items[i].classList.contains('flipped')) {
            flipped_item = list_items[i];
            // if flipped list item is scrolled past top of list ...

            // then do something...
        }
}
});
```

Relevant css...

```
ul.color-list {
    background-color: Black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

li.color-list-item {
    background-color: Black;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 4px;
    border-left: 4px solid White;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px !important;
    height: 42px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: border .25s ease;
    transition: border .25s ease;
}
```

The html is just a ul element with id="color-list" and a height of 60vh. The list items are generated dynamically when the page loads.

```
<ul id="color-list">

</ul>
```

Comment: Please add your code to your question, and separate your question into paragraphs to avoid this wall of text you now seem to have. Check if you can add a [mcve]

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) may help you achieve what you're looking for, but it may be a more advanced topic/feature if you're new to web development.

Comment: Posted the code

Comment: I added the Js, css and html. Sorry guys and gals I was at work coding in the bathroom so I was rushing when I first posted this.

Comment: StackOverflow is important and all, but you can really feel free to wait until you finish up in the bathroom to do your posts.

Comment: Just said i was "coding" in the bathroom. Not using it. Read more carefully...